# What happens if we kill the JVM process during transaction execution?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.

What happens if someone kills the JVM process during exectuion transactional batch-update (batch size = 50) when some of the queries in the batch are already executed?

What will be in the database?

Comment: Yes, what happens? - Expected behaviour is that the transactions that are not committed, time out on the DB side and are rolled back.  Transactions that are committed are, well, committed.

Comment: @ochi Yes, I couldn't reproduce the circumstance myself, so don't know for sure. I'm interested if the rest update queries will be eceuted. So what do we see in the database?

Comment: the rest of the update queries where? in the DB? - if the JVM is killed, there are no remaining update queries on the batch (until next batch execution, which re-starts the entire thing, not only the non-executed ones).  There are mechanism to restart from where it left off on previous executions (depending on which frameworks you are using)

Comment: @ochi I don't know how batch-update's actually implemented. If so, I wouldn ask it. Batch update is, as far as I know, an optimized way to execute set of queries...

Comment: `What will be in the database?` -> Everything and only what was successfully committed. Everything else won't make it. (If your "batch" process doesn't use transactions then your DB will probably be in an inconsistent state - at least from the business perspective, because from a strict data perspective, PostgreSQL, as a decent ACID RDMS, is able to guarantee durability [aka what was committed/inserted remains committed/inserted]).

Comment: If some have actually executed but not others then it's not a batch.  In a transactional batch, either all of them are executed in reality, or none of them are.

Comment: Try to imagine this: 1- jvm starts the transaction; 2- database do the process; 3 - jvm sends the commit to end transaction if you kill the JVM no matters what happens in the database it will not run the commit therefore it will rollback

Comment: @PeterLawrey So, it's imposible for a batch to be in a state when there're not yet executed queries?

Comment: @JorgeCampos So, in a non-trasactional batch there will be incosistent state? So, should we wrap any batch-update into a transaction?

Comment: For a true batch, yes - that would not happen.  Problems is, many people develop batch updates poorly and end up committing every 'n' number of updates leaving the batch partially committed.  This can create numerous issues if not handled properly.  Best to use a framework like spring-batch that helps with all those issues.

Comment: Yes, if you delegate the transaction responsability to the database THEN you will likely have inconsistences (also depending on your database implementation).

Comment: @St.Antario Queries can be batched up and the server can check whether the whole batch is likely to fail as you go, but no other connection can see the changes you have perform in part, either other connections will see all changes or none.

Comment: @PeterLawrey JDBC doesn't specify the transactional behavior of batch execution when `autoCommit=true`, so in that case the database could have committed data that - business-wise - is inconsistent. TL;DR: disable auto commit when executing batches.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel auto commit only makes sense if you don't need multi statement transactionality. If you turn it off you can still commit() every statement if that is what you want.

Comment: @PeterLawrey JDBC doesn't specify how batch execution should work with autoCommit=true, and leaves it up to the individual databases and driver implementations. Some drivers rewrite (prepared statement) batches to a single statement, other databases have APIs that allows them to send a batch of parameters for execute, and only commit afterwards, etc. So the commit point with auto commit might vary between implementation (and for batch size within an implementation), so your earlier comment about transactionality is too simplistic if you consider autoCommit=true

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expected behaviour is that the transactions that are not committed, time out on the DB side and are rolled back. Transactions that are committed are, well, committed.

Integrating answers from various comments:

> If some have actually executed but not others then it's not a batch. In a transactional batch, either all of them are executed in reality, or none of them are. –  Peter Lawrey

Another

> Try to imagine this: 1- jvm starts the transaction; 2- database do the process; 3 - jvm sends the commit to end transaction if you kill the JVM no matters what happens in the database it will not run the commit therefore it will rollback –  Jorge Campos

Lastly, for PostgreSQL

> *What will be in the database?* -> Everything and only what was successfully committed. Everything else won't make it. (If your "batch" process doesn't use transactions then your DB will probably be in an inconsistent state - at least from the business perspective, because from a strict data perspective, PostgreSQL, as a decent ACID RDBMS, is able to guarantee durability [aka what was committed/inserted remains committed/inserted].) –  acdcjunior

Comment: I'll be spreading upvotes to all the contributors for this answer.  Thanks guys

Answer (score 6):

There are two situations in which the connection can be: either in auto-commit mode or not in auto-commit mode (by calling `Connection#setAutoCommit(false)`).

In the first case, when executing a batch of update SQL commands, there could be partial execution of commands, i.e. some commands may be committed and others still not executed. See this quote from the documentation of [`Statement#executeBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()):

> If one of the commands in a batch update fails to execute properly, this method throws a `BatchUpdateException`, and a JDBC driver may or may not continue to process the remaining commands in the batch. However, the driver's behavior must be consistent with a particular DBMS, either always continuing to process commands or never continuing to process commands.

When a connection is not in auto-commit mode, then only when a call to `Connection#commit` is returned can we assume that all submitted commands are committed. Either all or none are committed after this call.

Comment: Note: if you are using auto commit mode, you have turned off batching.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Couldn't you explain why?

Comment: @St.Antario a batch by definition batch up a series of operations/messages/tasks. When you commit, you say this is the end of the batch. By auto-commiting, you are making the batch size 1.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The exact behavior under autoCommit=true depends on the driver. Some drivers will execute the entire batch as one transaction, while others execute the individual items of the batch as separate transactions.